# LibreOffice: a XSLT stylesheet to generate a slideshow?

Tags: xslt, slideshow, openoffice.org, libreoffice

A **libreoffice** document is a zip file containing (among other thing) some XML files.

```
s$ unzip -t test.odp
Archive:  test.odp
    testing: mimetype                 OK
    testing: Configurations2/statusbar/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml   OK
    testing: Configurations2/floater/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/popupmenu/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/progressbar/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/menubar/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/toolbar/   OK
    testing: Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/   OK
    testing: content.xml              OK
    testing: styles.xml               OK
    testing: meta.xml                 OK
    testing: settings.xml             OK
    testing: META-INF/manifest.xml    OK
No errors detected in compressed data of test.odp.
```

I would like to dynamically generate an ODP slideshow using **XSLT** (and the xsltproc + the element `<xsl:document/>` ) from a xml file that could look like this:

```
<slideshow>

  <slide>
    <title>Slide 1</title>
    <content>blablablablablablablabal</content>
  </slide>
  <!-- (....) --->
  <slide>
    <title>Slide N</title>
    <content>blablablablablablablabal</content>
  </slide>
</slidesho>
```

Is there any existing XSLT stylesheet for this ?

The file **content.xml** is complicated, what would be the minimal content for an odp, a HelloWorld.odp,  that could work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimial valid presentation file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0">
  <office:body>
    <office:presentation/>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

A simple file with some basic content would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content office:version="1.2"
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
    xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
    xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
    xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0">
  <office:body>
    <office:presentation>
      <draw:page draw:master-page-name="">
        <draw:frame presentation:style-name="" svg:width="25.199cm"
          svg:height="3.506cm" svg:x="1.4cm" svg:y="0.837cm" presentation:class="title">
          <draw:text-box>
            <text:p>Title</text:p>
          </draw:text-box>
        </draw:frame>
        <draw:frame presentation:style-name="" svg:width="24.639cm"
          svg:height="12.178cm" svg:x="1.4cm" svg:y="4.914cm" presentation:class="subtitle">
          <draw:text-box>
            <text:p>My Text</text:p>
          </draw:text-box>
        </draw:frame>
      </draw:page>
    </office:presentation>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

I'd suggest getting an XML editor like [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) that supports ODF to play with this. Having the [specifications and RNG](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office) for the ODF version that you want to use might help, too.