# styling content.xml in an openoffice/libreoffice document

Tags: xml, styles, openoffice.org, libreoffice

This is the next episode of my previous question [LibreOffice: a XSLT stylesheet to generate a slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364524)

I'm now generating **content.xml** with **XSLT**.

It is possible in libreoffice/content.xml to add an **inline** style in a `text:p` . Something like   `xhtml:span` (see below ) ?

```
  <draw:page draw:master-page-name="">
    <draw:frame presentation:style-name="" svg:width="25.199cm"
      svg:height="3.506cm" svg:x="1.4cm" svg:y="0.837cm" presentation:class="title">
      <draw:text-box>
        <text:p>My name is <xhtml:span style="color:red;"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xhtml:span></text:p>
      </draw:text-box>
    </draw:frame>
  </draw:page>
```

or do I need to declare all the named style elsewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <text:span> in a <text:p> and yes, you have to declare all named styles elsewhere.

The <text:span> needs an end tag of course.  You'll need to use the correct styling attributes and that is non-trivial.  The <xsl:value-of> element is not going to fly either.  You'll need to check into the ODF support for fields, I think.

The only attributes on the <text:span> element are at most one text:class-names and at most one text:style-name.

The text:style-name value is the name of a style that is then defined elsewhere.  The text:class-names attribute is a value of space separated style names.

Further details can be found in the ODF specification.  I recommend the OpenDocument Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument) Version 1.2, Part 1.  You can find all of it at http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/, including a Zip of the full set. You can also get more information by setting some attributes on a partial run in a paragraph and see what the content.xml is like and where the styles that end up being referenced are defined.